# Making a sitcky footer even on browser resize

Tags: html, css

After searching for this topic for a while in internet, i came here with no clue. I am writing html pages where i am in a need of sticky footer, that should not change it's position even on browser resize.

What i am suffering now is, when i am changing my browser size, i am getting a horizontal and vertical scroll bar. But my footer is displaying above all the div elements. Here is my code.

HTML,

```
<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="welcomeDiv">
        <label>Welcome Message</label>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Footer -->
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footerDiv">
        <h5 class="copyright">&copy; 2013 </h5>
        <h5 class="footer_info">Career | Help</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Footer */
div#footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
height: 4em;
clear: both;
width: 1580px;
padding: 0;
border: 1px solid #000;
} 

div#footerDiv {
font-size: 10px;
color: grey;
text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
}

div#footerDiv h5 {
font-size: 9pt;
font-weight: 300;
}

div#footerDiv h5.copyright {
margin-left: 10px;
float: left;
}

div#footerDiv h5.footer_info {
margin-right: 10px;
float: right;
}
/* Body Content styles */
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
}
```

Can some one please help me what's wrong in my code. I dont want to see cssstickyfooter.com anymore.

Thank you,

Comment: if you want it to always stick to the bottom, why not just make it `position:fixed`?

Comment: @paulitto: But my requirement is, i still need to display the footer at the bottom of the page only, when a browser is resized... I feel very tired now :(

Comment: You asked for a `sticky footer, that should not change it's position even on browser resize`, `position:fixed` would do exactly that. If you want it to be at the bottom only when browser gets resized, then you should bind onresize javascript handlers to change its position. If you want to place it somewhere depending on window size - use css media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Add width and height to body and make footer width as 100%

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin : 0;
}
div#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 4em;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sK9Wu/2/

Comment: still i am getting the same. To be clear, my footer wants to stay in the bottom, even my browser gets resized. Means, when i am resizing my browser, i should only see my footer by scrolling to most bottom.

Comment: same issue :( no clue :(

Comment: I think, you will get horizontal scroll bar.but i.e due to border css.If you use border-top and border-bottom. then you won't get scroll bars.